# how to get equidistant log scaling of y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to use log_2 scale on the y axis for my plot and the ticks to be equidistant. However, what I get is. How can I achieve equidistant ticks with equal spacing?

Using the very same code for all three plots, only the first one is the way I intended it to be. I dont get it

```
axs[i].set_yscale("log", base=2)
axs[i].yaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(base=2))
axs[i].yaxis.set_minor_locator(LogLocator(base=2))
axs[i].plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Controlling tick spacing in log-scale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27258156/controlling-tick-spacing-in-log-scale)

Comment: it does not. It doesnt change the plot at all

Comment: The problem is not th number of ticks but their logarithmic spacing...

Comment: How about providing [MInimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: conceived a mwe and it works, so the problem is in my code apparently. I will keep checking. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following code gives equidistant

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import LogLocator
x = np.linspace(0, 10, 10)
y = 2**x

f = plt.figure()
ax = f.add_subplot(111)
plt.yscale('log', base=2)
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(LogLocator(base=2))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(LogLocator(base=2))
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

[image]