# scatterplot skips major ticks with log scale even with manual spacing

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, logarithm, xticks

I'm plotting points on a log-log scatterplot with `matplotlib`. The `x` coordinate of these points rises twice as fast (exponentially speaking) than the `y` coordinate, which means that the `x` axis is twice as densely packed when plotted on a square plot.

Here's the code and the graph it produces:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as tkr

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,8))
ax: plt.Axes

# Log scale
ax.set_xscale("log")  # Needed for a log scatterplot. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52573929/9352077
ax.set_yscale("log")
# ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.LogLocator(base=10))
# ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.LogFormatterSciNotation())
# ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.LogLocator(base=10))
# ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(tkr.LogFormatterSciNotation())

# Plot points
t = range(1, 10_000_000, 1000)
x = [e**2 for e in t]
y = t
ax.scatter(x, y, marker=".", linewidths=0.05)

# Grid
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.grid(True)

fig.savefig("./test.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

[image: missing major ticks]

By default, matplotlib seems to want a square grid, and hence skips every other power of 10 on the `x` axis. Supposedly, the 4 lines I have commented out -- a combination of a locator and a formatter -- are the way to customise the spacing of the major ticks. See e.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27258626/9352077). **Yet, uncommenting them produces the same exact figure, with missing major ticks.**

How else, if not with `LogLocator(base=10)`, can I change the spacing between the ticks on the log scale? Here's roughly what it should look like (I've highlighted the changes in red, but they should of course be gray):

[image: no more missing major ticks on log scale]

Comment: `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(tkr.LogLocator(numticks=999))` and `ax.set_aspect('equal')` see [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KmvEf.png)

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney The aspect ratio suggestion is actually quite nice, I hadn't thought of that. Not sure why you didn't leave your comment as an answer.

Comment: If it's covered in the duplicate(s), I usually just leave a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want the output to look like?
You will probably want a more robust solution for the x_ticks.
I removed that t value you had because you didn't need it

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 8))
ax: plt.Axes

# Log scale
ax.set_xscale("log")  
ax.set_yscale("log")

# Plot points
y = range(1, 10_000_000, 1000)
x = [e**2 for e in y]

ax.scatter(x, y, marker=".")

# Grid
ax.set_axisbelow(True)
ax.grid(True)
ax.set_xscale("log")
ax.set_xticks([10**x for x in range(0, 14)])



fig.savefig("./test.pdf", bbox_inches='tight')
```

Comment: Your comment is correct that this is not general enough, since the `0` and `14` are both magic numbers.